# How should one worship shivalinga at home

Tags: shiva, gods, shiva-purana, shiva-lingam, agni-purana

I wish to know about what material of shivling can one have at home. I have read that crystal and narmada shivling are best to be kept at home. At the same time, I have also read that mud shivling is the best type to have at our home.

Also please clarify how should pranprathishta be done for home shivalinga. And how shivling should be worshipped at home